# Show textfield with datepicker when I change value of selectbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, datepicker

I want to show textfield with datepicker when change value of selectbox.
This is my html code.

```
<select name="buyrent" id="buyrent" onchange="CheckRent(this.value);" />
    <option value="1">Rent</option>
    <option value="2">Buy</option>
</select>
<input type='text' id='start' name='start' class='fieldkecil'/>
<input type='text' id='end' name='end' class='fieldkecil'/>
```

This is my javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CheckRent(val){
  var element=document.getElementById('start');
   if(val=='1')
     element.style.display='block';
   else
     element.style.display='none';
  var element=document.getElementById('end');
   if(val=='1')
     element.style.display='block';
   else
     element.style.display='none';
  }
</script>
```

And this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input.fieldkecil').Zebra_DatePicker();
});
</script>
```

What I want is, when i choose 'Rent, 'start' and 'end' will show with zebradatepicker. When i choose 'Buy', they will hide.
Thank you.

Comment: If you want `#start`/`#end` to have `Zebra_DatePicker()`, why is your selector - `input.fieldkecil`? are you looking for `$('#start,#end').Zebra_DatePicker();`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this `start` to `end` date picker when The second date picker’s starting date is the value of the first date picker + 1

```js
function CheckRent(val){
  var element=document.getElementById('start');
   if(val=='1')
     element.style.display='block';
   else
     element.style.display='none';
  var element=document.getElementById('end');
   if(val=='1')
     element.style.display='block';
   else
     element.style.display='none';
  }

$('#datepicker-example7-start').Zebra_DatePicker({
  direction: true,
  pair: $('#datepicker-example7-end')
});

$('#datepicker-example7-end').Zebra_DatePicker({
  direction: 1
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://stefangabos.ro/wp-content/themes/zebra/cache/css/104fc4056ad53fbc1d0eb8dfa97c7010_6871998126.css" type="text/css">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stefangabos.ro/wp-content/themes/zebra/cache/javascript/c3c7293f00563706bd22bc16055aad92_7122815240.js"></script>

<select name="buyrent" id="buyrent" onchange="CheckRent(this.value);" >
    <option value="1">Rent</option>
    <option value="2">Buy</option>
</select>

<form action="javascript:void(0)" method="post">
<div>
<span class="Zebra_DatePicker_Icon_Wrapper" id="start">
  <input id="datepicker-example7-start" type="text" readonly="readonly">

</span>
  <span class="Zebra_DatePicker_Icon_Wrapper" id="end">
    <input id="datepicker-example7-end" type="text" readonly="readonly">  
  </span>
</div>
</form>
```